# How to reverse_complementary several strings in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I get the complementary reverse for dna? following formula works for first string but when I add the second string in the list it does not work.

```
dna = ['CAG', 'AGT']

def reverse_complementary (char):
    my_dictionary = {"A": "T", "C": "G", "G": "C", "T": "A"} 
    return "".join([my_dictionary[i] for i in reversed(char)])

print("reverse_complementary =" , reverse_complementary(dna))
```

Comment: Please provide expected and observed outputs.

Comment: Did you originally run it with just the string `'CAG'`, not a `list`. That would be your problem.

Comment: I run it with this dna = ['CAG', 'AGT']

Answer (score 2):

If you pass a `str` to `reverse_complementary`, it will reverse and
translate the characters, which is what you want.

If you pass a `list` of `str` objects, as you’re doing here, it will
reverse the `list`, then try to look up each `str` in the `dict`, and
that will fail.

How to fix it? That depends on whether you want to pass single DNA
sequences or lists of them. The former seems more generic, so I’ll go
with that.

`reverse_complementary` already works with strings, so that’s unchanged.
We need to call it differently:

```
dna = ['CAG', 'AGT']

for s in dna:
    print("reverse_complementary =" , reverse_complementary(s))
```

Edit: how to print results as a list.

With a loop:

```
lst = []
for s in dna:
    lst.append(reverse_complementary(s))
print("reverse_complementary =" , lst)
```

With a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
lst = [reverse_complementary(s) for s in dna]
print("reverse_complementary =" , lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform the translation on each of your strings seperatly (and not the list itself), this can be done with a loop or with `map` or an explicit list-comprehension, for example:

```
def reverse_complementary(char):
    my_dictionary = {"A": "T", "C": "G", "G": "C", "T": "A"} 
    return ["".join([my_dictionary[i] for i in reversed(seq)]) for seq in char]
```

However when you want to map characters to other characters it's generally better to use [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) and [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
to_complement = str.maketrans({"A": "T", "C": "G", "G": "C", "T": "A"})

def reverse_complementary(char):
    return [seq[::-1].translate(to_complement) for seq in char]
```

The `[::-1]` is another (also more efficient) way of reversing a string.

Comment: But this code does not give complementary reverse, it is just reverse

Comment: @Saram When I call it with `reverse_complementary(['AAT'])` (with either of these functions) it gives me `['ATT']` so I don't think it just reverses.